# Downloading FTP file from authorized section

Tags: php, file, iis, download, ftp

I have a PHP website on IIS 8, with authorized section.

I'd like to add a functionality so that logged in users can download files, for which have rights (information about files assigned to user are stored in database).

These files are stored on authorized FTP server (file size is 10MB-500MB).

I'd like to ask if there is some way to download just the file user has rights to, for example I was thinking about generating some unique link to a file so the user can download it, but without logging to FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

If each user already has a login to the FTP server and the permissions are setup correctly on their folders - you could integrate a PHP FTP section relatively easily which uses the logged in users (of the website) FTP credentials, presuming you have them in the database and just traverse the folders returned from ftp_nlist()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Here is a tutorial covering, logging in, retrieving directory contents and getting a file - the 3 things you will need

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/19945-basic-ftp-tutorial/